# Woocommerce shows empty columns

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, archives

In my wordpress site, i installed woocommerce.  In archieve categories and shop page the products not setting correctly.

They looks like:

```
XXX
  X
XX
```

But I want to display correctly in the grid:

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

Comment: I got the answer.  See below.  And thanks to @fuxia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer.  By setting a particular height to the  (only height and it don't need width), I got the answer as i Need.

Thankyou